# Data transfer between two pages in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I am using next js and I am new.I have three buttons on page A and I want to transfer '1', '2' or '3' to page B by clicking on each button.I am currently using `router.push` but it does not work.Because when I want to put the value in `useEffect` on page B, it is done with a delay.

```
export default function A() {
return (
<Button1 onClick={() => {router.push({
                pathname: "/B",
                query: {
                  value: "1",
                },
              });
            }}
/>
<Button2 onClick={() => {router.push({
                pathname: "/B",
                query: {
                  value: "2",
                },
              });
            }}
/>
<Button3 onClick={() => {router.push({
                pathname: "/B",
                query: {
                  value: "3",
                },
              });
            }}
/>
)
}
```

and B page is

```
export default function B() {
  const { value } = router.query;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value is :", value);
}

},[])
```

Did I choose the wrong method, or is it better to change `useEffect`?
Thank you for your support

Comment: next js support is extremely weak in stackoverflow ://///

Comment: you can use nexjts link feature too if you need some example check this link 
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing

Comment: I tested your code and it's the correct way to transfer data between pages. also, you can use a dynamic route.